# BeanValidation to check if delete is possible

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation

How can I use BeanValidation to validate record before delete? For example I can only delete record when `executeDate` field is in the future.

I'm using with success beanvalidation in my project. It's annotation based configured. I use it by `@Valid` annotation on Controller method. It's Spring based MVC application.

my environment:

```
<hibernate4.core.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate4.core.version>
<spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.search.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.search.version>
```

Edit:
I have seen this: [hibernate validator - different groups on create, update, delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930623/hibernate-validator-different-groups-on-create-update-delete), and Hibernate Documentation also, but it is steel not clear for me. 
If I have validation working so far do I need only add special case for delete? I'm confused what steps I need to do for get only this one feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hibernate validator - different groups on create, update, delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930623/hibernate-validator-different-groups-on-create-update-delete)

Comment: have seen it before, but doesn't help me :(

Comment: Does this mean that an entity can be deleted only when there are constraint violations for the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your persistence configuration

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remov">MyDeleteGroup</property>
```

Add this annotation to your date field

```
@Past(groups=MyDeleteGroup.class)
```

Delete Group `MyDeleteGroup` is just a marker interface like `javax.validation.groups.Default`

Comment: Works perfect!
Assumed it can not be so easy :)

Comment: Does this mean that an entity can be deleted only when there are constraint violations for the entity?

Comment: @Sunnyday: it mean that an entity can be deleted only if there is NO constraint VIOLATION in the contraints of group 'MyDeleteGroupe'

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot users:

application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            group:
             pre-remove: com.your_package.MyDeleteGroup
```

or

application.proeprties

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove=com.your_package.MyDeleteGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

[see this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/) for BeanValidation documentation

you can use @Past annotation for your case

see section 6.1

```
<event type="pre-delete">
    <listener class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener"/>
</event>
```

Comment: @Past is ok, but how to check it only when deleting not saving.