# Spring Boot REST · @Constraint for delete?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on a system's back end that uses Spring Boot, REST, HATEOAS, Hibernate and PostgreSQL. For validation, I started using classes that `extend org.springframework.validation.Validator`. It works well, but only for calls made by the front end. For calls made in the back end, such as by using `EntityManager`, they don't fire. I've managed to have another validator being called in this situation by using `@Constraint` for `ElementType.TYPE`, but it only gets called for `create` and `save` methods.

Is it possible to use this validator to validate on `delete` methods too? There's a project [here](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/springbug20180404/src/ea470880ab5b1e9de9cbc8c3e6c1393d406c3a45/com/project/validator/?at=master) that's a non operational subset of the project I'm working on, containing the validators I mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

*P.S.:* I'd rather avoid manually calling the validators whenever I call a repository method in the back end.

*P.P.S.:* [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930663/1781376) answer makes me believe it's possible, but I couldn't translate the XML configuration to JavaConfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. In `application.properties`, add:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove=javax.validation.groups.Default
```

The linked question told me which property I needed, but I didn't know where to place it. I tried to use custom Java configuration and even `persistence.xml` configuration, but several other things failed.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html), I learned that "[...] all properties in `spring.jpa.properties.*` are passed through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the local `EntityManagerFactory` is created." So I just added that prefix and it worked.

Comment: I followed your answer, and the validation worked. But it's giving me an error 500, instead of a 400.

Comment: Error 500 means an untreated error happened in the application running Spring, such as an untreated exception. It could be anything.