# Spring Boot REST · application.properties property causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Continuing from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802765/spring-boot-rest-constraint-for-delete), that same property that I needed to add to `application.properties` to make `ConstraintValidator` works, `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove`, is causing a NullPointerException when I try to delete an entity containing a list of the same type as a member. Simpler entities get deleted just fine. I even removed all validations, but it changes nothing.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/springbug20180404/src/f215e7f8799cbcf25cd928df2dfd370c19c36ae6/src/main/?at=master)'s a project that's a non operational subset of the project I'm working on, [here](https://bitbucket.org/GuiRitter/springbug20180404/src/f215e7f8799cbcf25cd928df2dfd370c19c36ae6/README.md?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)'s the maven dependency tree, and here's the stack trace:

```
2018-04-17 11:09:09.052 ERROR 8920 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.]
2018-04-17 11:09:09.069 ERROR 8920 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCollection.isValid(NotEmptyValidatorForCollection.java:34) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.notempty.NotEmptyValidatorForCollection.isValid(NotEmptyValidatorForCollection.java:20) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:357) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:126) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:86) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:116) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:109) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:534) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:497) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:466) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:381) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreDelete(BeanValidationEventListener.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.preDelete(EntityDeleteAction.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.deleteById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeDeleteById(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeDeleteById(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:152) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.lambda$deleteItemResource$5(RepositoryEntityController.java:428) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:421) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.project.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

Please help me make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (sort of). Actually, I didn't just included that property. It's the removal of the `org.springframework.validation.Validator`s that caused the `javax.validation` validators to stop working. I found out that I needed to have a `org.springframework.validation.Validator` registered with the `before|afterCreate|Save|LinkSave|Delete` events and that I had to either call the complex entity's linked entity getter or change it's `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

My colleague gave me the suggestion when I mentioned that the NPE happens at a Hibernate code line that reads `if ( persister.isExtraLazy() ) {` (see top of stack trace).

Doesn't look like the right way of doing things, but it's working for now. If someone has something to add, I'll be grateful.